# Ext.net version issue

Tags: extjs, ext.net

In grid I have below lines in ext.net, working fine in V1.X but create problem in V2.x

```
<Listeners>                                                          
    <HeaderClick Handler="return performSort(this, columnIndex);"
</Listeners>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Ext.NET Breaking_Changes document:

http://examples.ext.net/#/Getting_Started/Release_Documents/BREAKING_CHANGES/

```
154. The GridPanel HeaderMouseDown and HeaderDblClick events have been removed. 

    Its HeaderClick and HeaderContextMenu have been moved to ColumnModel/GridHeaderContainer.
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: Added code sample to demonstrate property configuration

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            Store store = this.GridPanel1.GetStore();
            store.DataSource = new object[] 
            { 
                new object[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" },
                new object[] { "test4", "test5", "test6" },
                new object[] { "test7", "test8", "test9" }
            };
        }
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET v2 Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />
        <ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanel1" runat="server">
            <Store>
                <ext:Store runat="server">
                    <Model>
                        <ext:Model runat="server">
                            <Fields>
                                <ext:ModelField Name="test1" />
                                <ext:ModelField Name="test2" />
                                <ext:ModelField Name="test3" />
                            </Fields>
                        </ext:Model>
                    </Model>
                </ext:Store>
            </Store>
            <ColumnModel runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <ext:Column runat="server" Text="Test1" DataIndex="test1" />
                    <ext:Column runat="server" Text="Test2" DataIndex="test2" />
                    <ext:Column runat="server" Text="Test3" DataIndex="test3" />
                </Columns>
                <Listeners>
                    <HeaderClick Handler="alert('Clicked ' + column.dataIndex);" />
                </Listeners>
            </ColumnModel>
        </ext:GridPanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But I already read that and wnat an example how can I implement that.